# Headful Github Actions for e2e testing

Tags: github-actions, e2e-testing, playwright, browserstack

I'm trying to e2e test my chrome extension with Github actions. I'm using Playwright framework. For Chrome extensions to work it is required to run the tests headful. Locally it is running fine, but when I push a commit, the github action fails

[image]

I tried the following command to increase verbosity and to setup a display

```
$> Xvfb :99 & node --trace-deprecation ./node_modules/.bin/playwright test
```

But it fails. The output is not more than just

```
Running 1 test using 1 worker
××F

  1 failed
    [chromium] › src/app.spec.ts:6:3 › Popup › our extension loads =================================
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Is something like this even possible or should I use something like Browserstack for this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, on BrowserStack we don't yet support testing Chrome extensions using Playwright. However it has already been marked as a feature request, our team is working on a solution for this and will launch it as a product feature in the near future.